# Vuejs: axios; Passing custom header in POST method

Tags: vue.js, axios

We are making an axios POST call from VueJs, need to pass a custom header. The way it is coded now, the custom header is not getting passed to the server script, other headers are getting passed. Please let me know what I might be doing wrong. Appreciate your help.

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: urltocall,
    data: strjson,
    config: {
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:1337',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'username': 'test1'
        }
    }
})
.then(function (response) { 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The headers object should not be put into a "config" object.

It's just...

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: urltocall,
    {
        headers: {
            ....
```

Comment: I get a "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" error if I try to send headers without the config object.

Comment: The Cross-Origin problem has nothing to do with your script. You need to set up your SERVER (not your client application) so that it handels cross-origin requests accordingly. I don't know about your server technology (Node, PHP, Symfony, ...) so this would be a separate topic

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this:

```
axios
    .post(urltocall, myDataAsJSON, {
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:1337",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "username": "test1"
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log("Success: " + response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("Error: " + error.response.data);
    });
```

By the way, based on your `'Content-Type': 'application/json',`, I know you're trying to send a JSON object, but where/what is this object?

Also, refer to the [Full documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I try to specify headers without the config, I get a CORS blocking error. "Cross-Origin Request Blocked"